# UNITY: Meshes created through code not aligning with vertices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, vertices

I have ran into this issue with Unity. In code, I have declared 13 vertices for each Hex. They are visible in the following picture as gizmos (the small, gray dots). Some vertices overlap each other, as each Hex is supposed to generate its own Mesh. I have done this to allow easy wrapping of the world.

[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsf5j.png)

As you can see, the first mesh at the very bottom left is generated at the correct position, but from then onward, each mesh is twice too much upwards or to the left. Upon selecting any of the Hexes, the correct mesh is highlighted (for instance, clicking on the top-left Hex highlights the top-left Mesh. The vertices are in the correct position and it seems to me that the triangles are also correctly placed, leaving me to wonder what is wrong with this. Below is the code that generates the meshes:

The following code is in the HexMap gameobject which handles the world generation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HexMap : MonoBehaviour
{
    //The reference to the prefab
    public GameObject hexPrefab;

    public int numRows = 10;
    public int numColumns = 10;

    private GameObject[,] hexes;

    void Start()
    {
        GenerateMap();
    }

    public void GenerateMap()
    {
        //Initiate array to store all hexes
        hexes = new GameObject[numRows, numColumns];

        //Loop through all rows for each column to generate hexes
        for (int c = 0; c < numColumns; c++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < numRows; r++)
            {
                //Instantiate hex and assign it to the hexes-array
                GameObject hexObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(hexPrefab);
                hexes[c, r] = hexObject;

                //Access the Hex.cs script within the Hex gameobject
                Hex hex = hexObject.GetComponent<Hex>();

                //Make the Hex a child of the HexMap gameobject (mainly for clarity in the Unity hierarchy)
                hexObject.transform.parent = this.transform;

                //Set the column and row values in the Hex.cs to the current column and row
                hex.SetValues(c, r);
                //Call the position-method in Hex.cs to calculate the position of the Hex (it's default position would be 0,0,0 but it's changed here)
                hexObject.transform.position = hex.Position();
                //Call the method in Hex.cs to create its mesh, vertices and triangles
                hex.CreateMesh();

                //Change the label on a hex to read its column and row (only for debugging)
                hexObject.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text = string.Format("{0},{1}",c,r);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the following code exists in the Hex.cs script, which is a component of each Hex that we instantiate:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Hex : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int column;
    public int row;
    public readonly int negativeDistance; //the negative distance is the negative of (column + row) (this will be used to calculate the distance between two hexes

    public Mesh mesh;

    public Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[13];
    public int[] triangles = new int[36];

    public float radius = 1f;
    static readonly float WIDTH_MULTIPLIER = Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdateMesh();
    }

    public void SetValues(int column, int row)
    {
        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;
        name = string.Format("Hex: {0},{1}", column, row);
    }

    //Returns the world-space position of this hex
    public Vector3 Position()
    {
        return new Vector3(HexHorizontalSpacing() * (column + row / 2f), 0, HexVerticalSpacing() * row);
    }

    //Returns the height of a single hex (from side to side)
    public float HexHeight()
    {
        return radius * 2;
    }

    //Returns the width of a hex (from point to point)
    public float HexWidth()
    {
        return WIDTH_MULTIPLIER * HexHeight();
    }

    //Returns the space between two hexes verticallrow
    public float HexVerticalSpacing()
    {
        return HexHeight() * 0.75f;
    }

    //Returns the space between two hexes horizontallrow
    public float HexHorizontalSpacing()
    {
        return HexWidth();
    }

    public void CreateMesh()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;

        vertices[0] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, row * 1.5f);
        vertices[1] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2 + Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 4, 0, row * 1.5f + 0.75f);  //1
        vertices[2] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2 + Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, row * 1.5f + 0.5f);  //2
        vertices[3] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2 + Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, row * 1.5f + 0);  //3
        vertices[4] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2 + Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, row * 1.5f - 0.5f);  //4
        vertices[5] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2 + Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 4, 0, row * 1.5f - 0.75f);  //5
        vertices[6] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, -1f + row * 1.5f);  //6
        vertices[7] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2 - Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 4, 0, row * 1.5f - 0.75f);  //7      
        vertices[8] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2 - Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, row * 1.5f - 0.5f);  //8       
        vertices[9] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2 - Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, row * 1.5f + 0);  //9
        vertices[10] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2 - Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, row * 1.5f + 0.5f);  //10
        vertices[11] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2 - Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 4, 0, row * 1.5f + 0.75f);  //11
        vertices[12] = new Vector3(column * Mathf.Sqrt(3) + row * Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, 1f + row * 1.5f);  //12

        triangles[0] = 0;
        triangles[1] = 12;
        triangles[2] = 1;


        for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
        {
            triangles[i * 3] = 0;
            triangles[i * 3 + 1] = i;
            triangles[i * 3 + 2] = i + 1;
        }

        UpdateMesh();
    }

    public void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;

        mesh.triangles = triangles;

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }

    public void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (vertices == null) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(vertices[i], .1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure if I'm getting it, the form of the resultant square should be a rect-square or the current general form (obtuse-angle-square)? In case of the first, they are to the right, not to the left, that is confusing me a little bit ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, probably too late - but since the question still is open and viewed, here is a short answer:

When you create the mesh in CreateMesh() you use the current column and row values to position the vertices. This would be ok if all Hex-cells were created in the same mesh, but since you create one mesh per Hex-cell and then position the Hex-cell, you should not use the column and row variables in the local mesh calculation.

```
    vertices[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    vertices[1] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 4, 0, 0.75f);  //1
    vertices[2] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, 0.5f);  //2
    vertices[3] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, 0);  //3
    vertices[4] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, -0.5f);  //4
    vertices[5] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 4, 0, -0.75f);  //5
    vertices[6] = new Vector3(0, 0, -1f);  //6
    vertices[7] = new Vector3(-Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 4, 0, -0.75f);  //7      
    vertices[8] = new Vector3(-Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, -0.5f);  //8       
    vertices[9] = new Vector3(-Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, 0);  //9
    vertices[10] = new Vector3(-Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 2, 0, 0.5f);  //10
    vertices[11] = new Vector3(-Mathf.Sqrt(3) / 4, 0, 0.75f);  //11
    vertices[12] = new Vector3(0, 0, 1f);  //12
```

And since all Hex-cells now have the same vertices, you can make one simple mesh and share it with all Hex-cells, no need to calculate several meshes with the same values.